# Crackling/drilling noise underneath Subwoofer/SSD on laptop

Tags: laptop, audio, ssd

I have this Lenovo Y720 laptop, which is making a strange crackling/drilling noise right at the SSD/Subwoofer area. It is not **very** noisy, but if I put my ear right under my laptop I can hear it clearly.
I have marked the area where the sound is loudest and therefor I believe it is from there the sound comes from. I have made a link to the sound too. I recorded the sound from the subwoofer hole, and it is loudest there, but that could be because there is a hole of course. The sound is also loud to the left of the subwoofer, which means the SSD area.

What I am sure it is not:

- The HDD, because that is replaced and the same noise was present before.
- The speakers
- The fans, as there are holes beneath them too and no sound, and they have been replaced too.
- The motherboard, as that has been replaced too, which means it is not the CPU and GPU too.

[Crackling sound](https://clyp.it/inb23bu3)

[Laptop section where the sound is loudest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMxE7.jpg)

[Laptop bottom from outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Kbf.jpg)

Comment: The SSD cannot make a sound.  So it must be the speaker, which means, it’s picking up interference.  **The sound is your fan.**

Comment: Do you mean that the fan is interfering with the subwoofer? Is that normal or something is defective?

Comment: I am saying it's either your subwoofer or the fan.  The SSD cannot make the sound.  There are no moving parts.  It is impossible for an SSD to create sound.

Comment: It must be the subwoofer then, as the fan is completely quiet when I listen underneath it :)

Comment: And the fan has been replaced too, I forgot to mention that in the post.

Comment: Are you sure don't have multiple fans?  Cause the subwoofer would only be picking up on interference.  Easy enough to verify.  Disconnect the cable to the speaker.

Comment: There are two fans in the laptop yes, but they were both replaced. I will try removing the cable to the subwoofer and listen, thank you.